# Why do echo $$, echo $(echo $$) and (echo $$) reveal the same PID?

Tags: bash, shell, process, subshell

As far as I know

```
echo $$
```

shows the PID of the current BASH I am in.

I do not know if the expasnsion **$(...command...)** runs the command in a subshell or the current shell, however

```
echo $(echo $$)
```

shows the same PID
But, as for **(...command...)** I was very sure, that the command is run inside a subshell and therefore in a shell with another PID than the current shell, but

```
(echo $$)
```

shows also the same PID

So, in all three cases the same PID,namely 1771, was displayed.
I am confused, based on what I learned so far, I would not have expected it.
Why?

Comment: [Try `echo $BASHPID`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASHPID).

Comment: This is what I found inside the manual for bash:

Comment: $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell,
              it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the
              subshell.

Comment: now I understand why people say RTFM

Comment: for those who do not know: in $$ , the second $ is the actual special character for the PID and the first $ tells the bash that the following character is to be understood as a special character

Comment: Thanks! 4 years old and this is exactly the RTFM I was looking for! But how do I get the calling subshell pid? Like $$PPID but for the calling subshell not the calling process that invoked the shell?